# Modal not appear after the Jquery Steps Form Submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

**I tried to display modal after the submission J query Step form. But some time modal immediately disappear and sometimes does not appear.**

The Following **code works fine on online simulator on SO** and modal appear perfectly. **But modal does not appear on my browser.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function adjustIframeHeight() {
        var $body   = $('body'),
            $iframe = $body.data('iframe.fv');
        if ($iframe) {
            // Adjust the height of iframe
            $iframe.height($body.height());
        }
    }

    // IMPORTANT: You must call .steps() before calling .formValidation()
    $('#student_questions')
        .steps({
            headerTag: 'h2',
            bodyTag: 'section',
   autoFocus: true,
   enableContentCache: true,
   transitionEffect: 'fade',
   transitionEffectSpeed: 170,
            onStepChanged: function(e, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
                // You don't need to care about it
                // It is for the specific demo
                adjustIframeHeight();
            },
            // Triggered when clicking the Previous/Next buttons
            onStepChanging: function(e, currentIndex, newIndex) {
                var fv         = $('#student_questions').data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
                    // The current step container
                    $container = $('#student_questions').find('section[data-step="' + currentIndex +'"]');

                // Validate the container
                fv.validateContainer($container);

                var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
                if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
                    // Do not jump to the next step
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            },
            // Triggered when clicking the Finish button
            onFinishing: function(e, currentIndex) {
                var fv         = $('#student_questions').data('formValidation'),
                    $container = $('#student_questions').find('section[data-step="' + currentIndex +'"]');

                // Validate the last step container
                fv.validateContainer($container);

                var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
                if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            },
            onFinished: function(e, currentIndex) {
                // Uncomment the following line to submit the form using the defaultSubmit() method
                $('#student_questions').formValidation('defaultSubmit');

                // For testing purpose
                $('#welcomeModal').modal();
            }
        })
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            // This option will not ignore invisible fields which belong to inactive panels
            exclude: ':disabled',
            fields: {
                subject_name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please Provide Subject Name'
                        }
                    }
                },
                chapter_name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please Provide Chapter Name'
                        }
                    }
                },
    qtype_name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please Provide Question Type Name'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

```css
.wizard .content {
    min-height: 100px !important;
 width: 74%;
}
.wizard .content > .body {
    width: 100% !important; !important; !important; !important;
    height: auto !important; !important; !important;
    padding: 15px !important; !important;
    position: relative !important;
}
.wizard > .actions {
     width: 74%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/jquery.steps/js/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/jquery.steps/css/jquery.steps.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/formvalidation/css/formValidation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
  <body>
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
 <h1>Now you are in Study section</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <div class="col-md-10">
   <!--Form-->
   <form id="student_questions" method="post" class="form-horizontal">        
   <h2>Choose Subject</h2>
   <section data-step="0">    
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Subject Name: </label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control" name="subject_name" id="subject_name">
       <option value="">Select Subject</option>
       <option value="e">English</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <h2>Choose Chapter</h2>
   <section data-step="1">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Select Chapter: </label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control" name="chapter_name" id="chapter_name">
       <option value="">Select Chapter</option>
       <option value="e">English</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>    
   <h2>Choose type of questions</h2>
   <section data-step="2">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Select Type of Question</label>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control" name="qtype_name" id="qtype_name">
       <option value="">Select Questions Types</option>
       <option value="e">English</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>           
   </form>
   <!--End Form-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="welcomeModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Completed...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: it's very odd, please tell your browser version and model.